# Calculate Rolling Sum Expense each 6 months for each customer using Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data set as below and I want to calculate Rolling Sum Expense each 6 months for each customer using  Pyspark.
I have using window in pyspark.sql.function but did not success.
I just wonder if anyone can help me with this.

Thank you.

In summary, the process is as follows:
[image: ![enter image description here]
Here is the sample data

```
d = [
    {'id': 1, 'Month': 1, 'expense': 11.0,}, 
    {'id': 1, 'Month': 1, 'expense': 15.0},
    {'id': 1, 'Month': 1, 'expense': 16.0}, 
    {'id': 1, 'Month': 2, 'expense': 12.0}, 
    {'id': 1, 'Month': 2, 'expense': 14.0}, 
    {'id': 1, 'Month': 3, 'expense': 6.0}, 
    {'id': 1, 'Month': 3, 'expense': 7.0}, 
    {'id': 1, 'Month': 3, 'expense': 4.0}, 
    {'id': 1, 'Month': 4, 'expense': 4.0}, 
    {'id': 1, 'Month': 5, 'expense': 6.0}, 
    {'id': 1, 'Month': 6, 'expense': 7.0}, 
    {'id': 1, 'Month': 7, 'expense': 8.0}, 
    {'id': 1, 'Month': 8, 'expense': 9.0},
    {'id': 2, 'Month': 1, 'expense': 1.0}, 
    {'id': 2, 'Month': 1, 'expense': 5.0},
    {'id': 2, 'Month': 1, 'expense': 6.0}, 
    {'id': 2, 'Month': 2, 'expense': 2.0}, 
    {'id': 2, 'Month': 2, 'expense': 4.0}, 
    {'id': 2, 'Month': 3, 'expense': 14.0}, 
    {'id': 2, 'Month': 3, 'expense': 17.0}, 
    {'id': 2, 'Month': 3, 'expense': 16.0},
    {'id': 1, 'Month': 4, 'expense': 4.0}, 
    {'id': 1, 'Month': 5, 'expense': 6.0}, 
    {'id': 1, 'Month': 6, 'expense': 7.0}, 
    {'id': 1, 'Month': 7, 'expense': 8.0}, 
    {'id': 1, 'Month': 8, 'expense': 9.0}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `rangeBetween` function to calculate the rolling sum.

I'm defining my frame boundaries as `rangeBetween(-1, 0)`. `-1` denotes one-off before the current row, and `0` represents the current row. Aggregating over this frame gives you a two-month rolling average:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w = Window().partitionBy("id").orderBy('Month')

df.groupBy("id", "Month").agg(F.sum(col("expense")).alias("total_expense")) \
  .withColumn("rank", F.row_number().over(w)) \
  .withColumn("two_month_rolling_sum", F.sum(col("total_expense")).over(w.rangeBetween(-1, 0))) \
  .filter(col("rank")!=1)\
  .drop("total_expense", "rank")\
  .orderBy("id", "Month").show()
```

Output:

```
+---+-----+---------------------+
| id|Month|two_month_rolling_sum|
+---+-----+---------------------+
|  1|    2|                 68.0|
|  1|    3|                 43.0|
|  2|    2|                 18.0|
|  2|    3|                 53.0|
+---+-----+---------------------+
```

Comment: Cena: thanks for your help!  It work well for the case of roll 2 months, but did not work for the case of 6 months rolling. I am not sure why. Here I tried to change the rangesBetween from -6 to 0 but it seems not work. Could you please suggest me how to fix it. I will modified my code for 6 months case for your easier to follow. Thank you.

Comment: HI Cena, thanks for your help! This approach work perfectly for sum and max. But now I would like to apply mean and std operation and this approach seems not reflect the nature of these operations, I just wonder if you know how to deal with these cases. Thank you.